# ¿se puede desplegar mas de un proyecto net core 2.1 en un servidor linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, centos7

una Consulta quisiera saber si en un servidor linux puedo desplegar mas de un proyecto net core 2.1.

en la configuración del kestrel [service] esta la opcion ExecStart. y apunta a mi proyecto. Pero que sucedería si quisiera agregar mas despliegues de otros proyectos en el mismo servidor. 
Como puedo desplegar mas proyectos asp net core 2.1 en un mismo servidor o como se configura?

```
[Unit]
Description=.NET Core App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/data/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /data/app/CoreTest.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-core
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PASO 1
configuracion .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=$scheme
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /blog/ http://127.0.0.1:84/
    ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://127.0.0.1:84/
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_nc.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_nc.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

PASO 2
Configuracion kestrel-service.service

```
[Unit]
Description=.NET Core App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/data/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /data/app/prueba.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-core
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

PASO 3

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:84")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();)
```

PASO 4
Permitir accesos al puerto elegido httpd

verifico estado del httpd y se muestra 'httpd_can_network_connect off'

```
sestatus -b | grep httpd
```

Para activarlo ejecute el comando

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

REFERENCIAS
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/permission-denied-in-apache-logs-when-used-as-a-reverse-proxy-790957647.html

Comment: para ver el log de apache redirigirse a /var/log/httpd/error_nc.log

Comment: considerar habilitar mod_rewrite
reference: https://arjunphp.com/enable-configure-mod_rewrite-apache-centos-7/